# Cannot close/delete docusign developer sandbox account

Tags: docusignapi

I have created a developer account on docusign. I don't need it anymore and I cannot find any way to close the account.

I have followed the [docusign link](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-do-I-cancel-or-downgrade-my-account) about closing accounts, but that didn't help. In my admin page I don't have an option to edit my plan or close my account. I cannot submit a support case either, as my developer account doesn't allow me to login to the support center, and I cannot ask docusign directly for information since that also requires, I assume, a full (non-developer) account.

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign Sandbox account is free and you are never billed for it. But even if you want to move ahead with closing the account, can you please try calling `1-800-379-9973` with your request.

Comment: Is that really the only way? I would preffer not needing to make international calls, they tend to be expensive...